# Derive the market demand function and market supply function

Tags: supply-and-demand, asset-pricing, demand

In the second page of this [paper](https://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/112/47/14557.full.pdf) Gjerstad et al derive the market demand and the supply for assets using the data shown in Table 1.

The table is [image]

The demand function they find is $Q = 94 – 0.4 P$ and the supply function is $Q = P/15 – 1$

I cannot understand how the functional form they find relates to the data in the table: can someone help me understand how do they derived it?

Comment: Can you please make the question more self-contained?

Comment: @Giskard Am I allowed to include the relevant parts of the paper in the question?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - allowed by whom? I specifically ask you to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hidden on the third page (left column, middle) you can find that the markets they set up experimentally comprised 8 buyers and 4 sellers. If you multiply the individual demand and supply values from Table 1 by the corresponding number of individuals, you get the linearly approximated demand and supply functions stated on the second page.